# Getting error: operation failed: Failed to connect to remote libvirt error when I try doing kvm migration using virsh on debian

Tags: qemu, kvm, virsh

I am getting the error message

error: operation failed: Failed to connect to remote libvirt URI qemu+ssh://mytargethostname.mydomain.com/system: Cannot recv data: Host key verification failed.: Connection reset by peer

when I try to run the kvm migration command like this

virsh migrate --verbose --live --p2p --tunnelled hosttomigrate qemu+ssh://mytargethostname.mydomain.com/system

I can successfully view the running vms on the target host when I run

virsh -c qemu+ssh://mytargethostname.mydomain.com/system list --all

Is there some special configuration that I may need for kvm ?